# How to implicitly extend a Function without losing type inference

Tags: scala, enrich-my-library

For a DSL I need to implicitly extend function values. For instance:

```
trait PimpedFunction[-A, +B] extends Function1[A, B] {
  def foo = 42
}

object PimpedFunction {
  implicit def pimp[A, B](f: Function1[A, B]): PimpedFunction[A, B] = 
    new PimpedFunction[A, B] {
      def apply(a: A) = f(a)
    }
}
```

A function that uses `PimpedFunction` could be defined as something like:

```
def takes(f: PimpedFunction[String, Int]) = f.foo
```

The problem is on the code that calls `takes`. The following works as expected:

```
takes((_: String).size)
```

But if I elide the parameter type the compile fails to infer it:

```
takes(_.size)
```

Can I change anything in order to help scalac's inference?

OBS: The real use case is related to this: https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/4542402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can allow your `takes` function to do the conversion itself, it'll work:

```
def takes(f: Function1[String, Int])(
  implicit f2pf: Function1[String,Int] => PimpedFunction[String,Int]
) = f2pf(f).foo
```

(you can overload `takes` to take either a PF or a regular function).

Comment: Thanks! I marked as correct since it really solves the problem as I presented. Unfortunately it doesn't work when the `pimp` function is implemented as a macro, but I'll raise the issue separately.